# How to access elements of a nested dictionary after creating it

Tags: python

I have created this below dictionary and want an output something like this:

```
main_dict = {
    'pins': 
        {
            'Category': ['General'], 
            'Contact': ['Mark'], 
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
        }, 
    'nails': 
        {
            'Category': ['specific'], 
            'Contact': ['Jon'], 
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
        },
    'board': 
        {
            'Category': ['General'], 
            'Contact': ['Mark'], 
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
        }, 
    'hammer': 
        {
            'Category': ['tools'], 
            'Contact': ['Jon'], 
            'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
        }
}
```

Output: 
    {'General': ['pins', 'board'], 'specific': ['nails'], 'tools': ['hammer']}

Comment: Hey @Heyya, can you clarify your last line a little bit? I'm confused. It seems like you want to create a list, but I'm not sure what you want from there. To access an inner value you can do this: `mainDict['firstKey']['field1']`

Comment: Please remove the irrelevant code that creates your dictionary and show us what your expected output looks like instead. I really can't tell what _"if field1==x then create a list named on value1 and append firstkey to that list named value1"_ is supposed to mean. Your question would be easier to understand if we could see the output you want to get.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. Where does `x` come from?

Comment: @Heyya I think you may have not finished typing your question!

Comment: @PeterDolan I know I can do mainDict['firstKey']['field1'] to get value1 but this is hardcoded, how can I generalize it. 
Example: 
MainDict : 
 {'pins': {'Category': ['General'], 'Contact': ['Mark'],  'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']},
 'nails': {'Category': ['specific'], 'Contact': ['Jon'],  'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a',  'description']}, 
 'board': {'Category': ['General'], 'Contact': ['Mark'],  'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']},
 'hammer': {'Category': ['tools'], 'Contact': ['Jon'],  'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a',  'description']}}

Comment: Output: 
General=list("pins" "board")
Specific=list("nails" )
Tools=list("hammer")

Comment: @Aran-Fey : Please see the above example....

Comment: @Heyya Thanks, that makes the question a lot more comprehensible. Please [edit] that information into your question though. And the code that generates your dict is still not relevant to the question and should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based of your comments I got an answer that seems to fit your requirements. First, the dict in question:

```
main_dict = {
        'pins': 
            {
                'Category': ['General'], 
                'Contact': ['Mark'], 
                'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
            }, 
        'nails': 
            {
                'Category': ['specific'], 
                'Contact': ['Jon'], 
                'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
            },
        'board': 
            {
                'Category': ['General'], 
                'Contact': ['Mark'], 
                'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a']
            }, 
        'hammer': 
            {
                'Category': ['tools'], 
                'Contact': ['Jon'], 
                'Description': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'description']
            }
}
```

Now, I'm assuming that `'Category'` is always going to be a list where we want the first element. If that's not the case the solution won't quite work.

From here, we should declare `Category` as the key we care about (`X` in your initial example) and also create an `answer` dict that we'll return at the end.

```
KEY = 'Category'
answer = {}
```

Next, we'll create the function that gives data to our answer dict.

```
for elem in main_dict:
    to_add = ' '.join(main_dict[elem][KEY])
    if to_add not in answer:
        answer[to_add] = [elem]
    else:
        answer[to_add].append(elem)
```

Finally, we print the result with `print(answer)` and get the following output:

`{'General': ['pins', 'board'], 'specific': ['nails'], 'tools': ['hammer']}`.

Hopefully this helps with your problem! If anything isn't clear or needs additional clarification please let me know.

edit: adding new answer:

```
construction = {'General': ['pins', 'board'], 'specific': ['nails'], 'tools': ['hammer', 'screwdriver', 'tape' ]}

longest_arr = 0
for elem in construction:
    if len(construction[elem]) > longest_arr:
        longest_arr = len(construction[elem])

lines_to_print = [[] for x in range(longest_arr)]

print(lines_to_print)
for elem in construction:
    construction[elem] = construction[elem] + [" "] * (longest_arr - len(construction[elem]))
    for index, item in enumerate(construction[elem]):
        lines_to_print[index].append(item)

for arr in lines_to_print:
    print (' '.join(arr))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, This works fine. Just one thing to add is if the category is multiple string meaning instead of "general" and "specific" if its "General xyz" and "specific abc" then how to handle that?

Comment: Is it still a single string (`"General xyz"`) or is it in an array (`["General", "xyz"]`)? Also, what would you want the output to be in this case?

Comment: if it is : 'Category': ['General', 'xyz'] then the output should be like this:  {'General xyz': ['pins', 'board']'}

Comment: @Heyya updated my answer to have this functionality. Added `' '.join(...`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I did get what I wanted. I will update the original question and remove unnecessary info.

Comment: the result we got above : 
    {'General': ['pins', 'board'], 'specific': ['nails'], 'tools': ['hammer' 'screwdriver' 'tape' ]}.
 How can I iterate over values of keys above and get an output something like this: 

Pins nails hammer \n
Board Empty screwdriver \n
Empty Empty tape \n

Comment: Hey @Heyya, What do you mean when you say `empty`? Should it be a space, or literally say `empty`?

Comment: Empty meaning space .

Comment: Added to original answer. Also, if my answer answered your question, will you upvote it and mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution to the problem :

```
        mainDict={'firstKey': {'field1': ['value1'], 'field2': ['value2']}, 'secondKey': {'field1': ['valuex'], 'field2': ['valuey']}}
        x = 'field1' # by x i assume some string that matches the key field1
        myListDict = {} # empty dictionary to store the variables
        for key in  mainDict.keys():
            for subkey in mainDict[key].keys() :
                if subkey == x :
                    myListDict[mainDict[key][subkey][0]] = key

        print(myListDict)
```

Output is :

`{'valuex': 'secondKey', 'value1': 'firstKey'}`

this is based on my understanding of the question asked or given information.
Hope this helps.